# Help drawing complicated image

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, technical-drawing

I am in the middle of writing my dissertation. I need help drawing this image in latex. Can anyone provide any guidance or help with the image?

Thank you[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is this a Sankey diagram?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt in plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to compile this with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path I, A, NU, P, R, S, G, E, B;
    I = unitsquare scaled 64;
    B = unitsquare shifted 1/2 down scaled 128 shifted point 3/2 of I shifted 8 left;
    A = unitsquare xscaled 48 yscaled 48 shifted point 1 of I;
    NU = origin {right} .. (60, 100) {50, 100}; 
    NU := NU for t=1 step -1/32 until 0: 
        -- point t of NU shifted 16 unitvector(direction t of NU rotated 90)
    endfor -- cycle;
    NU := NU shifted point 3 of A;

    R = origin {right} .. (50, -100) {48, -100};
    R := R for t=1 step -1/32 until 0: 
        -- point t of R shifted 20 unitvector(direction t of R rotated 90)
    endfor -- cycle;
    R := R shifted point 1 of A;
    
    P = unitsquare xscaled 80 yscaled 28 shifted point -1 of R;

    E = origin {right} .. (30, -10) {30, -10};
    E := E for t=1 step -1/32 until 0: 
        -- point t of E shifted 4 unitvector(direction t of E rotated 90)
    endfor -- cycle;
    E := E shifted point 1 of P;
    
    G = unitsquare xscaled 32 yscaled 20 shifted point -1 of E;
    
    S = point 2 of P {right} .. point 7/8 of NU .. point 3 of I  {right};
    S := S for t=2 step -1/32 until 0: 
        -- point t of S shifted 4 unitvector(direction t of S rotated -90)
    endfor -- cycle;

    fill B withcolor 7/8; draw B;
    fill S withcolor (1, 1, 31/32);
    draw subpath (0, 2) of S;
    draw subpath (3, length S - 1) of S;
    forsuffixes $=I, A, NU, R, P, E, G:
        fill $ withcolor (1, 1, 31/32);
        if length $ = 4: label(str $, center $); fi
        draw subpath (0, 1) of $;
        draw subpath (2, length $ - 1) of $;
    endfor

    label.urt("NU", point 3/2 of NU);
    label("R", point 3/2 of R);
    label.lrt("E", point 3/2 of E);
    label("S", point 1/2 of S shifted 12 right );
    path bb; bb = (superellipse(right, up, left, down, .82)) scaled 6 shifted 13/16[point 0 of B, point 2 of B];
    unfill bb; label("B", center bb);

    ahangle := 28;
    picture Arrow; Arrow = image(drawarrow 12 left -- 2 right) scaled 3;
    draw Arrow shifted point -1/2 of I;
    drawarrow (4 left --  8 right) shifted point 3/2 of G;
    drawarrow interpath(1/2, subpath (1/2, 5/8) of R, subpath (18, 14) of R);
    drawarrow interpath(1/2, subpath (1/2, 5/8) of NU, subpath (18, 14) of NU);
    for a=5/8, 5/4:
        drawarrow subpath(a, a+1/8) of S shifted 8 unitvector(direction a+1/16 of S rotated -90);
    endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you think you would like to learn more about Metapost, please follow the link at the top for tutorials and reference material.